# Checking If Element Has Certain Class And Certain ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've seen threads about checking if an element has a class and a certain id but the way mine is set up those answers aren't possible.

I have a list of projects laid out in a masonry layout with each project having a class of `project`. Each project has a unique id that is named by the title of the project. When the user right clicks on a project, the default Google Chrome menu is replaced by a custom menu that has two options,
`Open Project In A New Tab` & `View Project Details`.

My current issue is getting the specific project the user right clicked on.

Here are my two ideas:

1. **Simple Version:** Check the ID of the project that the user right clicked on.
2. **Complicated Version:**  Get the top and left offset of the div and combine them to get the top left point of the custom menu.
   Then check if that point is in between the `top, left` point of the project
   and the `top + projectImg.height(), and left + projectImg.width()` to get the bottom right corner of the project.

I am leaning towards the simple version but this is my problem with it:

```
if($(".project").is("#project1name")) {
    // True
}
```

The problem with this is that since all the projects have a class of `project` it counts all of them true if at least one of the projects has the given id the `if` statement is checking for.

Here is the code I have setup for the page:

```js
var resizeTimer;
$(window).on("resize", function() {

  if ($(window).width() > 1600) {
    $(".content").css("width", "1521px");
  }
  if ($(window).width() <= 1600 && $(window).width() > 1400) {
    (".content").css("width", "1268px");
  }
  if ($(window).width() <= 1400 && $(window).width() > 1200) {
    $(".content").css("width", "1015px");
  }
  if ($(window).width() <= 1200 && $(window).width() > 1000) {
    $(".content").css("width", "762px");
  }
  if ($(window).width() <= 1000 && $(window).width() > 800) {
    $(".content").css("width", "509px");
  }
  if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
    $(".content").css("width", "256px");
  }

  clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    var footer = ($(".content").offset().top * 2) + $(".content").height();
    $(".footer").css("top", footer);
  }, 250);

}).resize();

// Trigger action when the contexmenu is about to be shown
$(".project").bind("contextmenu", function(event) {

  // Avoid the real one
  event.preventDefault();

  // Show contextmenu
  $(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).

  // In the right position (the mouse)
  css({
    top: event.pageY + "px",
    left: event.pageX + "px"
  });
});


// If the document is clicked somewhere
$(document).bind("mousedown", function(e) {

  // If the clicked element is not the menu
  if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {

    // Hide it
    $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
  }
});


// If the menu element is clicked
$(".custom-menu li").click(function() {

  // This is the triggered action name
  switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {

    // A case for each action. Your actions here
    case "newTab":
      alert("first");

      break;

    case "second":
      alert("second");

      break;
  }

  // Hide it AFTER the action was triggered
  $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #212121;
}

.content {
  background: #424242;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 1521px;
  margin: 150px auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.project {
  display: inline-block;
}

.project:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04);
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.custom-menu {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0;
}

.custom-menu li {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.custom-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #DEF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='custom-menu'>
  <li data-action="newTab">Open In New Tab</li>
  <li data-action="viewDetails">View Details</li>
</ul>
<div class="content">
  <a href="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Projects/WordCounter/baseplate.php"><img src="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Images/wordCounter.png" height="150px" width="250px" class="project"></img>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Projects/CalmForm/baseplate.php"><img src="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Images/calmForm.png" height="150px" width="250px" class="project"></img>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Projects/Timer/baseplate.php"><img src="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Images/timer.png" height="150px" width="250px" class="project"></img>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Projects/SimpleTHREE_Cube/baseplate.php"><img src="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Images/simpleCube.png" height="150px" width="250px" class="project"></img>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Projects/SimpleTHREE_DrawingBox/baseplate.php"><img src="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Images/boxLine.png" height="150px" width="250px" class="project"></img>
  </a>
</div>
```

The way the simple version would work is once you have right clicked on the project in the `$(".project").bind("contextmenu", function (event)` it would check which project you clicked on and bind the `li` elements in the context menu with the respected link tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is *by far* the best solution to your issue, and is quite simple to achieve.

Firstly you need to add an `id` attribute to the `.project` elements, as this was missing in your original HTML. Then you can store the `id` of the element that causes the `contextmenu` event in the `data('id')` of the menu.

When an option is chosen from the menu you can then retrieve the `data('id')` from the menu and use it to know which project is required.

There is a couple of things to note about your code though. Firstly, `<img />` tags are self closing, so it's `<img />`, not `<img></img>`. Secondly, I don't want to sound disparaging, but your `resize` logic with the timer is frankly, horrific. You should refactor that to use CSS media queries ASAP. I realise you're doing a calculation in JS to position the `footer`, but even that I'm certain can be fixed by better designed HTML and CSS.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$(".project").bind("contextmenu", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).css({
    top: event.pageY + "px",
    left: event.pageX + "px"
  }).data('id', this.id); // set the chosen id here...
});

$(document).bind("mousedown", function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {
    $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
  }
});

$(".custom-menu li").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).closest('.custom-menu').data('id'); // get the chosen id here...
  console.log(id);

  switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
    case "newTab":
      console.log("open new tab...");
      break;

    case "viewDetails":
      console.log("get details...");
      break;
  }

  $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #212121;
}

.content {
  background: #424242;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 1521px;
  margin: 150px auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.project {
  display: inline-block;
}

.project:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04);
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.custom-menu {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0;
}

.custom-menu li {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.custom-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #DEF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='custom-menu'>
  <li data-action="newTab">Open In New Tab</li>
  <li data-action="viewDetails">View Details</li>
</ul>
<div class="content">
  <a href="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Projects/WordCounter/baseplate.php">
    <img src="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Images/wordCounter.png" height="150px" width="250px" class="project" id="project-A" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Projects/CalmForm/baseplate.php">
    <img src="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Images/calmForm.png" height="150px" width="250px" class="project" id="project-B" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Projects/Timer/baseplate.php">
    <img src="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Images/timer.png" height="150px" width="250px" class="project" id="project-C" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Projects/SimpleTHREE_Cube/baseplate.php">
    <img src="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Images/simpleCube.png" height="150px" width="250px" class="project" id="project-D" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Projects/SimpleTHREE_DrawingBox/baseplate.php">
    <img src="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Homepage/Images/boxLine.png" height="150px" width="250px" class="project" id="project-E" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: To be honest. I don't even remember why I had it as a timer. It was completely unneeded